# mailing list app for ruby on rails ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mass-emails

Im looking for a ruby on rails mailing list manager,
where you can login and manage your mailing list see some stats on send mail, etc

Is there any such thing available in ruby on rails as an opensource project?
I havent been able to find anything usefull even not here on stackoverflow

Comment: Sending mail, especially mass emails, can be very complicated. Have you thought about using Sendgrid? You can track opens / other stats with sendgrid. If you're looking for a more full featured mailing list service, you could try Mailchimp or Aweber, both of which have API's that you could plug into.

Comment: I know there are commercial solutions available, but want to build something myself

Comment: I just wrote an opensource example app with similar purposes. Here is my [related stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313504/rails-simple-newsletter-mailing-list-with-notification-of-new-search-results-v), and here is the [NotiSearch code on GitHub.com](https://github.com/duccioarmenise/NotiSearch). Of course if you like it you can fork/contribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ZList is a simple yet powerful mailing list application and is built on Rails. It can send mail to an unlimited number of recipients, can be configured as announcement only or it can be fully interactive. Subscribers can view and reply entirely by email. All discussions are archived so you can go back anytime to see what was said.

Here's a link to the gem's github page:

https://github.com/bensie/zlist

Comment: Nice, after all didn't expect anyone would come up with something useful.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [MailyHerald](http://mailyherald.org). It is an opensource Rails gem for managing and sending mailings. It integrates with your app, allows to you maintain multiple mailing lists and send various types of mailings.

It has nice web-ui for easy management and you can integrate it with your application authentication mechanism.